# Build error after migration from tfs to git using git-tfs

Tags: git, azure, tfs, git-tfs, tfs-migration

I migrated a .Net project from TFS to git using git-tfs tool. The migration was successful I built it in my PC, and it worked fine but when I pushed it to Azure DevOps (Normal Visual Studio .gitignore added) and then cloned it back to Visual Studio it is having Metadata error :
[image]

The funny thing is when I downloaded the project as a Zip from the DevOps it is being built and working fine. I tried almost everything from sending the whole dll files, bin, and packages folder to Devops, and cloning it still not working. Also, I copied the bin and packages folder from the working project to this one, still not working.

Note: I also test one of the other project and migrate it the same way, and the same thing happened to it, Thats why I believe there might be some problem in the migration process itself.

Any idea what might be the problem, or how is it technically possible, is hard to understand. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you !!!

Comment: You should remove the `packages` directory from version control; binaries should not be committed to Git repositories as a general rule. I'd recommend using a tool like filter-repo or BFG to permanently remove them from your repo's history as well as from the tip.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I did it only for testing to see if it works or not. Otherwise used gitignore to ignore those binaries files.

Comment: Is the `packages` directory in the TFVC repo? Can you remove it before migration or exclude it from the migration to git?